# RVM or ASDF which one is good to manage different ruby versions?

Tags: rvm, asdf

As I am planning to install ruby in my Mac machine for various projects. There are different Vesion manager , particularly I am considering both RVM and ASDF. Which one is good ?

RVM or ASDF both I can install but curious to know which one is more powerful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to maintain only ruby then you can go with rvm. suppose if you are going to play with more plugins like node, java along with ruby you can choose asdf.